# How to change store views with its root category in magento 2 from frontend

Tags: magento2

i am new to magento as well SO, I am trying to setup an magento website with two different store, 1 store have clothes related category and other one shoes related and I want to switch store view with its root categories.

so if someone switch to store 1 (cloths) he should only see clothes category and if switch to store 2 (shoes) then should display only shoes categories.

I have setup an website with two store and created separate categories for them and did necessary set up following with this link https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2.html

but I don't know how to switch store from front-end.

[image]

Create some different Root category for website and view.

[image]

Unable to display 2nd view product on home page...!!

Please Help

Comment: did you enable the newly crated store view?

Comment: yes my all view are Enable.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of the store view you have created